# While doing docker-compose build getting Build failure issue?

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

```
FROM java:8
FROM maven:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml /app
RUN mvn clean
RUN mvn compile
RUN mvn install

COPY . /app
RUN mvn clean install
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/target/Brabo-Asset-Service-Web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-spring-boot.jar"]
```

Getting this error:

```
java: /app/src/main/java (add: main, clean: false, plugin: null, outputOptions: null)
[INFO]     grpc-java: /app/src/main/java (add: main, clean: false, plugin: null, outputOptions: null)
[INFO] Resolving artifact: io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.15.0, platform: linux-x86_64
[INFO]     Processing (java): NodeLevelService.proto
protoc-jar: executing: [/root/protocjar8340208475023305576/bin/protoc.exe, -I/tmp/protocjar1489995214004248376/include, -I/app/src/main/resources, --java_out=/app/src/main/java, /app/src/main/resources/NodeLevelService.proto]
protoc-jar: caught exception, retrying: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/root/protocjar8340208475023305576/bin/protoc.exe": error=2, No such file or directory
protoc-jar: executing: [/root/protocjar8340208475023305576/bin/protoc.exe, -I/tmp/protocjar1489995214004248376/include, -I/app/src/main/resources, --java_out=/app/src/main/java, /app/src/main/resources/NodeLevelService.proto]
protoc-jar: caught exception, retrying: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/root/protocjar8340208475023305576/bin/protoc.exe": error=2, No such file or directory
protoc-jar: executing: [/root/protocjar8340208475023305576/bin/protoc.exe, -I/tmp/protocjar1489995214004248376/include, -I/app/src/main/resources, --java_out=/app/src/main/java, /app/src/main/resources/NodeLevelService.proto]
```

Comment: You never use the image `java:8`. You can safely remove it from the Dockerfile

Comment: Can you share the pom file? It looks like the problem is there.

Comment: @Stefano i am using openjdk:8

Comment: you're using the jvm coming from maven which incidentally is java 8 but you're not using the docker image `java:8`. You should check how the multistage builds work in docker.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with @stefano in regards to looking into doing a multistage build, but essentially your specific is issue is due to the fact that you are running a maven build without including/copying your source code first, so I believe your Dockerfile should look something like so:

```
FROM maven:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN mvn clean install
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/target/Brabo-Asset-Service-Web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-spring-boot.jar"]
```

Comment: You can check this out for an example of a springboot multistage build: https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/#_multi_stage_build